# Lightning aura:unescapedHtml does not render unordered lists

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html

I am trying to display a Terms of Service component in lightning. The client needs to be able to change the body of the ToS, so we are passing it as a raw string from Apex. If I pass the following string (and I can confirm it is received as-is within the component):

```
This is a list.
<ul>
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
</ul>
<p>and some text</p>
```

and try to render it with

`<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.fieldBody}" />`

the result is just the inner text of each element rendered on a separate line without bullet points. `<b>` tags and `<p>` tags seem to render the same way they would with html.

Why is `aura:unescapedHtml` not rendering my unordered list?

Comment: This https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/7b18be0e788740bf72e7d5712dd1b17c0902be8e/aura-components/src/main/components/aura/unescapedHtml/unescapedHtmlRenderer.js#L18 and this https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/2f5861898f177b88c54a7fe1147afeb8175089be/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/util/Util.js#L811 look like they should work. Does wrapping the first line in `<p>...</p>` make any difference?

Comment: I think you need to add the slds class for the bullet point list. Can remember exactly but something like slds-list--bullet. Since by default ul is rendered without bullets, numbers, etc

Comment: I did try several things I didn't bother to show here, wrapping the first line with `<p>` being one, wrapping everything in `<div>`, etc. but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Eric Yes, I added `class="slds-list--dotted"` and it worked! Is there a reason why regular `<ul>` doesn't work? The documentation seems to be a bit misleading on this one

Comment: The CSS is based on the lightning design system so by default it renders without those. Added as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the slds class for the bullet point list. Can remember exactly but something like slds-list--<s>bullet</s>dotted. Since by default ul is rendered without bullets, numbers, etc

Comment: Yes the class was `slds-list--dotted`. Thanks!